# How to jump to a line inside current view without scroll window

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

If we jump, using YouCompleteMe, in vim to a line that is already inside current view, it will put cursor to that line, and make that line be in center by scroll window.

for example, current window shows line 100 to line 200, and cursor is on line 160. Now we jump to line 110, which can be seen in current window view. After jumping, line 110 is in the center and window shows line 60 to 160.

I expect that any jump(including come back by ) won't scroll window if target line is inside current view, just put cursor to target place. How can I do this?

PS. I'm actually using YCM for jumping.

Comment: you should reword your question so the FIRST thing you mention is YCM

Comment: you should also mention what command you are using to jump

Answer (score 0):

After you go to the target line, try pressing `zz`.
I think this is what you are looking for. There are `zt`, `zb`, do `:h zt` to check out what those commands do.

You can create something else, e.g. I have:

```
nnoremap zl zt4<c-y>¬
```

Comment: The problem is exactly the vim DO the `zz` job automatically for me, which is not expected if target line can be seen in the view(Just jump cursor, without scrolling window).

Comment: @forrestJiang if you pressed `23G` vim will NOT do `zz` automatically, unless you config vim to do so. If you wrote the configuration, you should know where did you set that.